# drop-down menu cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css

down menu cuts off when I hover on the menu. I'm assuming it has something to do with how tall my header section is but I do not what to make the header section bigger I just want to see my drop-down section over the header. I tried doing a z-index and it didn't work. I might be putting it in the wrong place but I'm not sure. If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this issue please let me know!

```js
;(function ($, document, window) {
    var
    // default settings object.
        defaults = {
            label: 'MENU',
            duplicate: true,
            duration: 200,
            easingOpen: 'swing',
            easingClose: 'swing',
            closedSymbol: '&#9658;',
            openedSymbol: '&#9660;',
            prependTo: 'body',
            appendTo: '',
            parentTag: 'a',
            closeOnClick: false,
            allowParentLinks: false,
            nestedParentLinks: true,
            showChildren: false,
            removeIds: true,
            removeClasses: false,
            removeStyles: false,
   brand: '',
            animations: 'jquery',
            init: function () {},
            beforeOpen: function () {},
            beforeClose: function () {},
            afterOpen: function () {},
            afterClose: function () {}
        },
        mobileMenu = 'slicknav',
        prefix = 'slicknav',

        Keyboard = {
            DOWN: 40,
            ENTER: 13,
            ESCAPE: 27,
            LEFT: 37,
            RIGHT: 39,
            SPACE: 32,
            TAB: 9,
            UP: 38,
        };

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;

        // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
        // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
        // future instances of the plugin
        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        // Don't remove IDs by default if duplicate is false
        if (!this.settings.duplicate && !options.hasOwnProperty("removeIds")) {
          this.settings.removeIds = false;
        }

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = mobileMenu;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
        var $this = this,
            menu = $(this.element),
            settings = this.settings,
            iconClass,
            menuBar;

        // clone menu if needed
        if (settings.duplicate) {
            $this.mobileNav = menu.clone();
        } else {
            $this.mobileNav = menu;
        }

        // remove IDs if set
        if (settings.removeIds) {
          $this.mobileNav.removeAttr('id');
          $this.mobileNav.find('*').each(function (i, e) {
              $(e).removeAttr('id');
          });
        }

        // remove classes if set
        if (settings.removeClasses) {
            $this.mobileNav.removeAttr('class');
            $this.mobileNav.find('*').each(function (i, e) {
                $(e).removeAttr('class');
            });
        }

        // remove styles if set
        if (settings.removeStyles) {
            $this.mobileNav.removeAttr('style');
            $this.mobileNav.find('*').each(function (i, e) {
                $(e).removeAttr('style');
            });
        }

        // styling class for the button
        iconClass = prefix + '_icon';

        if (settings.label === '') {
            iconClass += ' ' + prefix + '_no-text';
        }

        if (settings.parentTag == 'a') {
            settings.parentTag = 'a href="#"';
        }

        // create menu bar
        $this.mobileNav.attr('class', prefix + '_nav');
        menuBar = $('<div class="' + prefix + '_menu"></div>');
  if (settings.brand !== '') {
   var brand = $('<div class="' + prefix + '_brand">'+settings.brand+'</div>');
   $(menuBar).append(brand);
  }
        $this.btn = $(
            ['<' + settings.parentTag + ' aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" class="' + prefix + '_btn ' + prefix + '_collapsed">',
                '<span class="' + prefix + '_menutxt">' + settings.label + '</span>',
                '<span class="' + iconClass + '">',
                    '<span class="' + prefix + '_icon-bar"></span>',
                    '<span class="' + prefix + '_icon-bar"></span>',
                    '<span class="' + prefix + '_icon-bar"></span>',
                '</span>',
            '</' + settings.parentTag + '>'
            ].join('')
        );
        $(menuBar).append($this.btn);
        if(settings.appendTo !== '') {
            $(settings.appendTo).append(menuBar);
        } else {
            $(settings.prependTo).prepend(menuBar);
        }
        menuBar.append($this.mobileNav);

        // iterate over structure adding additional structure
        var items = $this.mobileNav.find('li');
        $(items).each(function () {
            var item = $(this),
                data = {};
            data.children = item.children('ul').attr('role', 'menu');
            item.data('menu', data);

            // if a list item has a nested menu
            if (data.children.length > 0) {

                // select all text before the child menu
                // check for anchors

                var a = item.contents(),
                    containsAnchor = false,
                    nodes = [];

                $(a).each(function () {
                    if (!$(this).is('ul')) {
                        nodes.push(this);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if($(this).is("a")) {
                        containsAnchor = true;
                    }
                });

                var wrapElement = $(
                    '<' + settings.parentTag + ' role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1" class="' + prefix + '_item"/>'
                );

                // wrap item text with tag and add classes unless we are separating parent links
                if ((!settings.allowParentLinks || settings.nestedParentLinks) || !containsAnchor) {
                    var $wrap = $(nodes).wrapAll(wrapElement).parent();
                    $wrap.addClass(prefix+'_row');
                } else
                    $(nodes).wrapAll('<span class="'+prefix+'_parent-link '+prefix+'_row"/>').parent();

                if (!settings.showChildren) {
                    item.addClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
                } else {
                    item.addClass(prefix+'_open');
                }

                item.addClass(prefix+'_parent');

                // create parent arrow. wrap with link if parent links and separating
                var arrowElement = $('<span class="'+prefix+'_arrow">'+(settings.showChildren?settings.openedSymbol:settings.closedSymbol)+'</span>');

                if (settings.allowParentLinks && !settings.nestedParentLinks && containsAnchor)
                    arrowElement = arrowElement.wrap(wrapElement).parent();

                //append arrow
                $(nodes).last().after(arrowElement);


            } else if ( item.children().length === 0) {
                 item.addClass(prefix+'_txtnode');
            }

            // accessibility for links
            item.children('a').attr('role', 'menuitem').click(function(event){
                //Ensure that it's not a parent
                if (settings.closeOnClick && !$(event.target).parent().closest('li').hasClass(prefix+'_parent')) {
                        //Emulate menu close if set
                        $($this.btn).click();
                    }
            });

            //also close on click if parent links are set
            if (settings.closeOnClick && settings.allowParentLinks) {
                item.children('a').children('a').click(function (event) {
                    //Emulate menu close
                    $($this.btn).click();
                });

                item.find('.'+prefix+'_parent-link a:not(.'+prefix+'_item)').click(function(event){
                    //Emulate menu close
                        $($this.btn).click();
                });
            }
        });

        // structure is in place, now hide appropriate items
        $(items).each(function () {
            var data = $(this).data('menu');
            if (!settings.showChildren){
                $this._visibilityToggle(data.children, null, false, null, true);
            }
        });

        // finally toggle entire menu
        $this._visibilityToggle($this.mobileNav, null, false, 'init', true);

        // accessibility for menu button
        $this.mobileNav.attr('role','menu');

        // outline prevention when using mouse
        $(document).mousedown(function(){
            $this._outlines(false);
        });

        $(document).keyup(function(){
            $this._outlines(true);
        });

        // menu button click
        $($this.btn).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $this._menuToggle();
        });

        // click on menu parent
        $this.mobileNav.on('click', '.' + prefix + '_item', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $this._itemClick($(this));
        });

        // check for keyboard events on menu button and menu parents
        $($this.btn).keydown(function (e) {
            var ev = e || event;

            switch(ev.keyCode) {
                case Keyboard.ENTER:
                case Keyboard.SPACE:
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (ev.keyCode !== Keyboard.DOWN || !$($this.btn).hasClass(prefix+'_open')){
                        $this._menuToggle();
                    }
                    
                    $($this.btn).next().find('[role="menuitem"]').first().focus();
                    break;
            }

            
        });

        $this.mobileNav.on('keydown', '.'+prefix+'_item', function(e) {
            var ev = e || event;

            switch(ev.keyCode) {
                case Keyboard.ENTER:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $this._itemClick($(e.target));
                    break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($(e.target).parent().hasClass(prefix+'_collapsed')) {
                        $this._itemClick($(e.target));
                    }
                    $(e.target).next().find('[role="menuitem"]').first().focus();
                    break;
            }
        });

        $this.mobileNav.on('keydown', '[role="menuitem"]', function(e) {
            var ev = e || event;

            switch(ev.keyCode){
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var allItems = $(e.target).parent().parent().children().children('[role="menuitem"]:visible');
                    var idx = allItems.index( e.target );
                    var nextIdx = idx + 1;
                    if (allItems.length <= nextIdx) {
                        nextIdx = 0;
                    }
                    var next = allItems.eq( nextIdx );
                    next.focus();
                break;
                case Keyboard.UP:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var allItems = $(e.target).parent().parent().children().children('[role="menuitem"]:visible');
                    var idx = allItems.index( e.target );
                    var next = allItems.eq( idx - 1 );
                    next.focus();
                break;
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($(e.target).parent().parent().parent().hasClass(prefix+'_open')) {
                        var parent = $(e.target).parent().parent().prev();
                        parent.focus();
                        $this._itemClick(parent);
                    } else if ($(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass(prefix+'_nav')){
                        $this._menuToggle();
                        $($this.btn).focus();
                    }
                    break;
                case Keyboard.ESCAPE:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $this._menuToggle();
                    $($this.btn).focus();
                    break;    
            }
        });

        // allow links clickable within parent tags if set
        if (settings.allowParentLinks && settings.nestedParentLinks) {
            $('.'+prefix+'_item a').click(function(e){
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });
        }
    };

    //toggle menu
    Plugin.prototype._menuToggle = function (el) {
        var $this = this;
        var btn = $this.btn;
        var mobileNav = $this.mobileNav;

        if (btn.hasClass(prefix+'_collapsed')) {
            btn.removeClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
            btn.addClass(prefix+'_open');
        } else {
            btn.removeClass(prefix+'_open');
            btn.addClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
        }
        btn.addClass(prefix+'_animating');
        $this._visibilityToggle(mobileNav, btn.parent(), true, btn);
    };

    // toggle clicked items
    Plugin.prototype._itemClick = function (el) {
        var $this = this;
        var settings = $this.settings;
        var data = el.data('menu');
        if (!data) {
            data = {};
            data.arrow = el.children('.'+prefix+'_arrow');
            data.ul = el.next('ul');
            data.parent = el.parent();
            //Separated parent link structure
            if (data.parent.hasClass(prefix+'_parent-link')) {
                data.parent = el.parent().parent();
                data.ul = el.parent().next('ul');
            }
            el.data('menu', data);
        }
        if (data.parent.hasClass(prefix+'_collapsed')) {
            data.arrow.html(settings.openedSymbol);
            data.parent.removeClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
            data.parent.addClass(prefix+'_open');
            data.parent.addClass(prefix+'_animating');
            $this._visibilityToggle(data.ul, data.parent, true, el);
        } else {
            data.arrow.html(settings.closedSymbol);
            data.parent.addClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
            data.parent.removeClass(prefix+'_open');
            data.parent.addClass(prefix+'_animating');
            $this._visibilityToggle(data.ul, data.parent, true, el);
        }
    };

    // toggle actual visibility and accessibility tags
    Plugin.prototype._visibilityToggle = function(el, parent, animate, trigger, init) {
        var $this = this;
        var settings = $this.settings;
        var items = $this._getActionItems(el);
        var duration = 0;
        if (animate) {
            duration = settings.duration;
        }
        
        function afterOpen(trigger, parent) {
            $(trigger).removeClass(prefix+'_animating');
            $(parent).removeClass(prefix+'_animating');

            //Fire afterOpen callback
            if (!init) {
                settings.afterOpen(trigger);
            }
        }
        
        function afterClose(trigger, parent) {
            el.attr('aria-hidden','true');
            items.attr('tabindex', '-1');
            $this._setVisAttr(el, true);
            el.hide(); //jQuery 1.7 bug fix

            $(trigger).removeClass(prefix+'_animating');
            $(parent).removeClass(prefix+'_animating');

            //Fire init or afterClose callback
            if (!init){
                settings.afterClose(trigger);
            } else if (trigger == 'init'){
                settings.init();
            }
        }

        if (el.hasClass(prefix+'_hidden')) {
            el.removeClass(prefix+'_hidden');
             //Fire beforeOpen callback
            if (!init) {
                settings.beforeOpen(trigger);
            }
            if (settings.animations === 'jquery') {
                el.stop(true,true).slideDown(duration, settings.easingOpen, function(){
                    afterOpen(trigger, parent);
                });
            } else if(settings.animations === 'velocity') {
                el.velocity("finish").velocity("slideDown", {
                    duration: duration,
                    easing: settings.easingOpen,
                    complete: function() {
                        afterOpen(trigger, parent);
                    }
                });
            }
            el.attr('aria-hidden','false');
            items.attr('tabindex', '0');
            $this._setVisAttr(el, false);
        } else {
            el.addClass(prefix+'_hidden');

            //Fire init or beforeClose callback
            if (!init){
                settings.beforeClose(trigger);
            }

            if (settings.animations === 'jquery') {
                el.stop(true,true).slideUp(duration, this.settings.easingClose, function() {
                    afterClose(trigger, parent)
                });
            } else if (settings.animations === 'velocity') {
                
                el.velocity("finish").velocity("slideUp", {
                    duration: duration,
                    easing: settings.easingClose,
                    complete: function() {
                        afterClose(trigger, parent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    // set attributes of element and children based on visibility
    Plugin.prototype._setVisAttr = function(el, hidden) {
        var $this = this;

        // select all parents that aren't hidden
        var nonHidden = el.children('li').children('ul').not('.'+prefix+'_hidden');

        // iterate over all items setting appropriate tags
        if (!hidden) {
            nonHidden.each(function(){
                var ul = $(this);
                ul.attr('aria-hidden','false');
                var items = $this._getActionItems(ul);
                items.attr('tabindex', '0');
                $this._setVisAttr(ul, hidden);
            });
        } else {
            nonHidden.each(function(){
                var ul = $(this);
                ul.attr('aria-hidden','true');
                var items = $this._getActionItems(ul);
                items.attr('tabindex', '-1');
                $this._setVisAttr(ul, hidden);
            });
        }
    };

    // get all 1st level items that are clickable
    Plugin.prototype._getActionItems = function(el) {
        var data = el.data("menu");
        if (!data) {
            data = {};
            var items = el.children('li');
            var anchors = items.find('a');
            data.links = anchors.add(items.find('.'+prefix+'_item'));
            el.data('menu', data);
        }
        return data.links;
    };

    Plugin.prototype._outlines = function(state) {
        if (!state) {
            $('.'+prefix+'_item, .'+prefix+'_btn').css('outline','none');
        } else {
            $('.'+prefix+'_item, .'+prefix+'_btn').css('outline','');
        }
    };

    Plugin.prototype.toggle = function(){
        var $this = this;
        $this._menuToggle();
    };

    Plugin.prototype.open = function(){
        var $this = this;
        if ($this.btn.hasClass(prefix+'_collapsed')) {
            $this._menuToggle();
        }
    };

    Plugin.prototype.close = function(){
        var $this = this;
        if ($this.btn.hasClass(prefix+'_open')) {
            $this._menuToggle();
        }
    };

    $.fn[mobileMenu] = function ( options ) {
        var args = arguments;

        // Is the first parameter an object (options), or was omitted, instantiate a new instance
        if (options === undefined || typeof options === 'object') {
            return this.each(function () {

                // Only allow the plugin to be instantiated once due to methods
                if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + mobileMenu)) {

                    // if it has no instance, create a new one, pass options to our plugin constructor,
                    // and store the plugin instance in the elements jQuery data object.
                    $.data(this, 'plugin_' + mobileMenu, new Plugin( this, options ));
                }
            });

        // If is a string and doesn't start with an underscore or 'init' function, treat this as a call to a public method.
        } else if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' && options !== 'init') {

            // Cache the method call to make it possible to return a value
            var returns;

            this.each(function () {
                var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + mobileMenu);

                // Tests that there's already a plugin-instance and checks that the requested public method exists
                if (instance instanceof Plugin && typeof instance[options] === 'function') {

                    // Call the method of our plugin instance, and pass it the supplied arguments.
                    returns = instance[options].apply( instance, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ) );
                }
            });

            // If the earlier cached method gives a value back return the value, otherwise return this to preserve chainability.
            return returns !== undefined ? returns : this;
        }
    };
}(jQuery, document, window));
```

```css
.dropdown{
 overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
 background-color: inherit;
 
}


.dropdown-content{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 z-index:2000;
}

.dropdown-content a{
 
 float:none;
 display: block;
 
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
 display:block;
}
.dropbtn{
 border:none;
 font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
 z-index: 3000;
}

header{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 z-index:1000;
 
}

#logowheader{
 background: url(footer_lodyas.png) no-repeat fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {
 
 
 

 
 
 
 .slicknav_menu{
 display:block;
  z-index: 1000;

 
  
}
 

 
header{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 
}

 
 #menu{
  display:none;
  z-index: 1000;
  
 }
 
 .slicknav_menu img{
  display:none;
  z-index: 1000;

 }
}

.main-nav {

  display: flex;
 padding-left: 0;
 font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right:40px;
 z-index: 1000;

 
 }
.main-nav a:hover{
color: white; 
}

.main-nav a:after{
 content: attr(data-txthover);
    max-width: 100%; 
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-width .3s ease-out;
}

.main-nav li:first-child {
margin-right: auto;
 

}
.main-nav a {
 color: #1FA0A3;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 transition: all .3s;
 z-index: 1000;
 /*display: block*/
}

#logo {
width: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
 
}

.main-nav li{
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 
}

#logowheader{
 
 width:300px;
 padding-left: 0;
 
 
}

#vp{
 color: white;
 
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin-right:20px;
 }

html, body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.center{
 margin-top: 150px;;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
 
}
```

```html
<header>

<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-7LkWEzqTdpEfELxcZZlS6wAx5Ff13zZ83lYO2/ujj7g="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>             
<script src="SlickNav-master/dist/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>  
            
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('#menu').slicknav();
 });
</script>
<nav>
<div id="fix">
<ul class="main-nav" id="menu">
 <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="logo"><img id="logo" src="logo.svg" alt="logo"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#logowheader">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#recent">Skills</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="dropbtn">
        <li><a href="#description">About</a></li></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="#">Work</a>
         <a href="#">Education</a>
         
        </div>
        
        </div>
       <li><a href="#iwant">Contact</a></li>
 </ul></div>
 </nav></header>
```

Comment: Your `header` CSS includes `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue exists because of `overflow:hidden` in **header**.

Check http://prntscr.com/es60ia

Comment: wow I cannot believe I missed that I really appreciate your looking into this! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Cheers :)